# Removing one list from another

Tags: python

In python (2.7) we can do:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [4 , 5]
>>> a + b
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

However we can't do a - b.

Since python seems to have something cool for nearly everything, what is the most python-esque to do a - b, in your opinion?

Similar question for dictionaries, which can neither do a + b, or a - b, where a and b are both dictionaries.  Thanks.

Comment: What would the result be for `[ 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1 ] - [ 1, 2 ]`?

Comment: @Juhana Brilliant question.   It would be: [3].

Comment: Then I'd say why not `[ 3, 1, 2, 1 ]`?

Comment: Valid question. But, for my particular case it's [3].  That's what I need.

Comment: Then you aren't really treating the lists as lists, but as sets (in the mathematical sense). Fortunately, the mathematical concept of a set is reflected in the standard library, as shown in Rob's answer.

Comment: @Karl.  True. Good point. Thanks.  In my case, I know I won't have duplicates.

Comment: python-esque? pythonic is the term you're looking for ;)

Comment: For the questions about what would one do [...] - [..], same thing applies to + as well. Just cuz python adds two lists doesn't mean that result is what one expects. That's how it works. This question is genuine for me too. There should've been a default operation.

Answer (score 15):

You can do this with sets:

```
>>> s = set([1,2,3] + [4,5])
>>> s - set([4, 5])
{1, 2, 3}
```

The main difference of course being a set cannot contain duplicate elements.

Comment: A `set` in python doesn't necessarily preserve the order of its elements

Comment: `set`, definitely the best thing to do

Answer (score 7):

I would do:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [2, 3]
>>> filter(lambda x: x not in b, a)
[1]
```

or using list comprehensions

```
[x for x in a if x not in b]
```

And it can be done the same way for dictionaries.

[Set](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set) has defined operator `-` and methods `difference` and `symmetric_difference`. If you are planning to make extensive use of that operations use set instead of list or dict.

Comment: That's `O(n*m)` - so if your list do not contain any duplicate elements, better use sets and the `-` operator.

Comment: Of course. That's why I wrote "If you are planning to make extensive use ..." :)

Answer (score 3):

I would try `[x for x in a if a not in b]`.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on the desired semantics of `a - b`.

If you just want the first elements, then slicing is the natural way to do it:

```
In [11]: a = [1, 2, 3]

In [12]: b = [4 , 5]

In [13]: ab = a + b

In [14]: ab[:len(a)]
Out[14]: [1, 2, 3]
```

If, on the other hand, you want to remove elements of the first list not found in the second list:

```
In [15]: [v for v in ab if v not in b]
Out[15]: [1, 2, 3]
```

The second type of operation is more naturally expressed using sets:

```
In [18]: set(ab) - set(b)
Out[18]: set([1, 2, 3])
```

Note that generally this does not preserve the ordering of the elements (since sets are unordered). If ordering is important, and `b` is likely to be long, converting `b` into a set may improve performance:

```
In [19]: bset = set(b)

In [20]: [v for v in ab if v not in bset]
Out[20]: [1, 2, 3]
```

For dictionaries, there already exists an in-place "addition" operation. It's called [`dict.update()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update).

Answer (score 1):

`y = set(b)`
`aminusb = filter(lambda p: p not in y,a)`

Comment: That's O(n+m), albeit using a `lambda` makes this solution a bit slower

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def list_sub(lst1, lst2):
    s = set(lst2)
    return [x for x in lst1 if x not in s]

list_sub([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 5], [1, 2])
> [3, 5]
```

It's an `O(n+m)` solution due to the fact that it's using a precomputed `set`, so membership lookup will be fast. Also, it will preserve the order of the original elements and remove duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my preferred options, one involve the use of for loop the other conversion to set. In case of small list size for loop is acceptable as can be seen for a list size of 10,

```
In [65]: d1 = range(10)

In [66]: d2 = range(1)

In [67]: %timeit [x for x in d1 if x not in d2]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 827 ns per loop

In [68]: %timeit list(set(d1)-set(d2))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.25 µs per loop
```

However if the list size is big enough, then you should probably use set,

```
In [69]: d1 = range(10000)

In [70]: d2 = range(1000)

In [71]: %timeit [x for x in d1 if x not in d2]
10 loops, best of 3: 105 ms per loop

In [72]: %timeit list(set(d1)-set(d2))
1000 loops, best of 3: 566 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Order is not preserved, but it has the result you want:

```
>>> def list_diff(a, b):
...     return list(set(a) - set(b))
... 
>>> print list_diff([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1], [1, 2])
[3]
```